# How do I integrate a multivariable function?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, integral

I have a function `f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)` where `n >= 1` that I would like to integrate. What algorithm should I use to provide a decently stable / accurate solution?

I would like to program it in Python so any open source examples are more than welcome!

(I realize that I should use a library but this is just a learning exercise.)

Comment: Algorithm for what? What is your problem? If you want to take variable arguments, you can check `args` and `kwargs`.

Comment: I want to integrate it. EDIT: It's a mathematical function. *

Comment: [Monte Carlo integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) works well for multidimensional integrals.

Comment: @sdasdadas oh. pardon me. The term `integrate` confused me. :)

Comment: @Blender That looks great - thanks! Bibhas: No problems, I forgot to mention that they are mathematical functions. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your context and the performance criteria. I assume that you are looking for a numerical approximation (as opposed to a algebraic integration)
A Riemann Sum is the standard 'educational' way of numerically calculating integrals but several computationally more efficient algorithms exist.

Comment: "several computationally more efficient algorithms exist." Such as?